# How to include JWT Token from POSTMAN into Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible, jwt, yaml, access-token

I am attempting to define a variable to hold the JWT token which I obtain from POSTMAN for the API. Here's my playbook definition:

```
---
 - name: Request EX API
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   tasks:
      - name: Get Ports
        uri:
            method: GET
            url: "https://api.domain.com/ex/v3/network/userport"
            return_content: yes
            headers:
               Accept: application/json
               Authorization: "JWT {{token.json.token}}"
            register: response
      - debug:
            msg: "{{ response.content }}"
```

And I encountered the error below:

```
lw@APMBC02D20RHMD6R playbooks % ansible-playbook play1.yml

PLAY [Request EX API] ********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform darwin on host localhost is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change this. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get Ports] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'token' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/Users/lw/Ansible-EX/playbooks/ex.yml': line 6, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n tasks:\n - name: Get Ports\n ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************* 
localhost : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0

lw@APMBC02D20RHMD6R playbooks %
```

Could anyone kindly help point out how do I include the variable to hold the JWT token from POSTMAN?

Comment: @jps - The earlier question was with regards to issues affecting the indentation. This issue here is with regards to having variables to hold JWT token from Postman.

Comment: Your question is kind of vague -- what have you already tried in order to make a dict containing the structure you expect?